# How to retrieve data from CSV files

Tags: python

How do I retrieve data from a CSV file that has been saved so that I can calculate an average using those numbers in Python?

It is for a system that allows the user to view scores and choose to calculate an average of the scores but the scores are updated each time the user plays the game.
I'm new to Python and understand how to sort data in lists but need to be able to get that data from a csv file so that I can then sort it accordingly.

Comment: A quick Google reveals https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

What is your code so far/what have you tried?

Simple example with pythons built-in CSV module:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        # do something
```

Comment: How do I print a specific row or column using this?